# Spring Security SAML with standard java application

Tags: java, spring-security, adfs, spring-saml

We have a requirement where we need to enable SAML authentication in our application for a customer that has ADFS as IDP.

After considering various options, I was able to get this working with Spring SAML security as provided in the documents. 
Now the issue is to integrate the SAML security with our application.

Unfortunately, our application is still a leagacy java application using servlets and jsp and not spring based. 
I was just wondering how can the 2 be integrated. The document mentions that this possible .However, i was unable to find any write up on it.

Can someone plz direct me to the relevant source that can provide guidelines for this approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes in package `org.springframework.security.saml.websso` contain the core of SAML processing functionality and are independent of Spring Security. They do contain few class imports from Spring, therefore Spring-core classes need need to be on the classpath, but the application itself doesn't need to use Spring/SpringSecurity.

You will need to re-implement yourself logic which is specific to Spring Security - package `org.springframework.security.saml` - e.g. `SAMLEntryPoint`, `SAMLProcessingFilter`, and call your implementation during your authentication lifecycle. Logic of these classes is simple, so enabling basic use-cases is pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks Vladimír for the guidance. I started with this approach . took me a while to understand the flow but I am catching up.                  
Currently , i am issuing a redirect call from my java application to /spring-security-saml2/saml/login . On successful authentication from ADFS, i am redirecting the user back to my java application by setting the RelayState property in SamlEntryPoint  . Now I need is to retrieve the userClaims in my java application. I was wondering what should be an ideal approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vladimír for the guidance. This is how i integrated a standard legacy java app with spring security for saml based authentication:

1. Modified securityContext.xml
   set idpDiscoveryEnabled=false
   set forceAuthN= true to force user to login when saml token expires
   updated defaulttargetURL in successHandler to authhandler.jsp page,present in spring security app, to redirect back to my application
2. I have a filter applied on all the web calls in my java app . This
   filter redirects the call to   /spring-security-saml2/saml/login
3. spring saml authenticates the user with ADFS.On successful authentication, user is redirected to authhandler.jsp
4. Authhandler.jsp is same as index.jsp but the retrieved claims are hidden fields here. These values in hidden fields are send back to my standarda java application.
5. Here my java application performs other application level authentication and proceeds as desired.

Would appreciate any suggestions for improvisation or identification of any flaws in the above approach